# C++ serializing and compressing vector<structs> in platform independent way

Tags: c++, serialization, vector, struct, cross-platform

I'm looking to serialize a vector to send as a message in zeromq. The struct will only contain basic types (bool, string, int, float).

Since I am transferring over the network, I would like to use some sort of compression to save bandwidth.

I'd also like this to be somewhat platform agnostic. I will be broadcasting from a Linux box, but recipients could be either Windows or Linux.

Third party libraries are OK, so long as it will be possible for them to work under both Windows and Linux.

To send the zeromq message, typically something like memcpy is used to 'load' the data.
http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-msg-data

Can somebody point me to the appropriate libraries and provide a simple sample code of the serialization/compression and ensuing de-serialization/decompression. The structs I'd like to send look something like the following:

```
struct sampledata {
  string testing_text;
  int testing_int;
  float testing_number;
  bool testing_bool;
}
```

I feel this must be a common C++ programming problem and there should be good solutions already developed for it.

Comment: Have you looked at [google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)?

Comment: There are probably a dozen different libraries to look at, I'm hoping somebody with experience doing this already can state what works and what doesn't so future readers and I don't have to spend a day investigating each individual option.

Comment: The problem is every library will be suitable for someone, depending upon their exact needs. This isn't a very good question for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a general-purpose serialization library; [there are many available options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats).

I like two in particular: Google's [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and Apache's [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/). You can use either with ZMQ.

If you visit the ZMQ [FAQ](http://www.zeromq.org/area%3afaq) (go to the "general" section), you will find that Protocol Buffers is one of the mentioned serialization formats for the broker.

Comment: Protocol Buffers also supports compression? And will work on a Windows platform?

Comment: Protocol Buffers is language neutral and platform neutral - it will work on Windows, Linux, etc..., and with APIs for many languages. Regarding compression - the resulting stream is binary, and you can apply whatever algorithm works for you (compression depends on the data, so it is hard to tell whether you will gain anything).

Answer (score 1):

I'd at least consider [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) in conjunction with a [Boost gzip-filtered stream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html).